# Installing zf-charts-master Zend Framework 3

Tags: zend-framework, composer-php, zend-framework3

I have trouble installing zf-charts-master.

I get this error:

> Class 'Phpro\Chart\ChartJs\Doughnut\DoughnutOptions' not found

What I did:
I downloaded the packages from git and extracted it to 
C:\wamp64\www\mysite\vendor\zf-charts-master

Then I edited the composer.json and added:

```
"require" : {
        "php" : "^5.6 || ^7.0",
        "zendframework/zend-component-installer" : "^1.0 || ^0.7 || ^1.0.0-dev@dev",
        "zendframework/zend-mvc" : "^3.0.1",
        "zfcampus/zf-development-mode" : "^3.0",
        "zendframework/zend-cache" : "^2.7.1",
        "zendframework/zend-db" : "^2.9",
        "zendframework/zend-mvc-form" : "^1.0",
        "zendframework/zend-json" : "^3.0",
        "zendframework/zend-log" : "^2.9",
        "zendframework/zend-mvc-console" : "^1.1.10",
        "zendframework/zend-mvc-i18n" : "^1.0",
        "zendframework/zend-mvc-plugins" : "^1.0.1",
        "zendframework/zend-psr7bridge" : "^0.2.2",
        "zendframework/zend-navigation" : "^2.9",
        "phpoffice/phpspreadsheet" : "dev-develop",
        "zendframework/zend-authentication" : "^2.5",
        "zendframework/zend-mvc-plugin-identity" : "^1.0",
        "zendframework/zend-session" : "^2.8",
        "zendframework/zend-math" : "^3.0",
        "zendframework/zend-crypt" : "^3.3",
        "doctrine/doctrine-orm-module" : "^1.1",
        "zendframework/zend-inputfilter" : "^2.8",
        "zendframework/zend-validator" : "^2.10",
        "zendframework/zend-form" : "^2.12",
        "zendframework/zend-mail" : "^2.10",
        "zendframework/zend-filter" : "^2.8",
        "phpro/zf-charts": "~0.1"
    },
```

In my Controller I added these use-statements because Eclipse suggested it:

```
use Phpro\Chart\ChartJs\Doughnut\DoughnutChart;
use Phpro\Chart\ChartJs\Doughnut\DoughnutData;
use Phpro\Chart\ChartJs\Doughnut\DoughnutDataset;
use Phpro\Chart\ChartJs\Doughnut\DoughnutOptions;
```

Here also a Screenshot of the folder structure (it is located in vendor):
[image]

So I think Eclipse found the classes but Zend doesn't. My question:
What is missing, do I have to add it somewhere else? Any help appreciated!

Comment: `composer dump-autoload`?

Comment: I did already, no help